# Add Mongoose validation for phone numbers

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to validate phone number is there ten numbers or not
But minlength only works with string. I want minlength trick for number. Any one can suggest

Answer (score 2):

```
const yourSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  phoneNr: {
    type: Number
  }
});

yourSchema.path('phoneNr').validate(function validatePhone() {
  return ( this.phoneNr > 999999999 );
});

yourModel = mongoose.model('yourModel', yourSchema);
```

Edit:

```
const yourSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  phoneNr: {
    type: String,
    match: /^(\()?\d{3}(\))?(-|\s)?\d{3}(-|\s)\d{4}$/,
  }
});
```

this regex works for the formats (123) 456-7890 or 123-456-7890 for Example. The expression is dependent on what format of input you want to allow obvsly. If you use this, you dont need the validation function anymore.

Comment: also i would recommend to use a String for your phone number because when they start with a 0, this will get lost along the way of saving (0123 = > 123 with numbers)

Comment: Thanks, it looks great, What are the commen practice in validating phone number.

Comment: there is something called Regular Expressions (regex) https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp which can be used to check if a string fits a certain pattern. I will edit my answer

Comment: @RaphaelEckert I don't think a phone number can begin with a 0